# Launcher and Panel do not start after booting to terminal

Tags: unity, boot, command-line, 13.04, xorg

I did a fresh install of 13.04 and I wanted to boot straight into the terminal. So in the /etc/default/grub file, I changed the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

This worked. However, now when I login and subsequently do "startx"....I see my desktop background, but the launcher and the panel never show up. What do I need to change to be able to startx into Unity when I want to start Unity? Did I do something wrong or is there a better way to boot into the terminal? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For `startx` to work, you will need an `.xinitrc` file. Also `.Xauthority` might cause problems here. Better would be to start the display manager. `sudo service lightdm start` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a desktop session, start like this `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`. That will load Unity, gnome-settings-daemon and the rest of the stuff that is required.